# Crystal report - listing all specific data in detail into footer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

So I'm creating a report that I want to pull a specific data from the details to the footer (not sure which footer I should use) and here's a example of the data.

```
Task    StartDate   WeekNum CompDate    Initial
1        13-Sep       38     16-Sep       TJ
1        20-Sep       39     24-Sep       TJ
5        13-Sep       38     16-Sep       DD
8        23-Aug       35     24-Aug       QA
7        2-Aug        32     7-Aug        QA
1        19-Jul       30     23-Jul       OP
3        1-Aug        31     20-Aug       EZ
5        1-Sep        36     14-Sep       MC
```

As of right now, I'm able to pull each row out and put it into the detail which I will suppress one I'm able to gather the right data out for the footer

What I want to do is display a table in a footer of a certain task with its CompDate and Initial if it matches the WeekNum but those that was missed or those that is pending. Like this

```
         Task 1     
WeekNum CompDate  Initial
1        Missed    Missed
2        Missed    Missed
3        Missed    Missed
…        
30       23-Jul     OP
…       
38       16-Sep     TJ
39       24-Sep     TJ
…..     
52       Pending   Pending
```

What I've done right now is made an Excel table template and that I've paste it on the crystal report and is trying to pull a row out so i can put it in the table but the only row I'm able to pull out is the latest or last detail in the report.

Any suggestion?

Comment: From where are you getting week num and task num? if some numbers are missing from database then also do you need to display those?

Comment: The week num is a formula that determine the week number. The task num is from a table. There will be missing numbers in the database that i still want to display them.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output, you need to do 2 things:

1. Go `Insert -> Group` and choose field `Task` to group by ascending order
2. Go `Report -> Report Sort Expert` and sort by field `WeekNum`

And then you have your data like you wanted. Only thing more to worry about is after adding a group you got 2 new sections (group header and group footer). On group header you put name of your task (field `Task`) and group footer is usually used for some summarized fields within groups or something similar. If you don't need to use any new sections then right click on them and chose suppress - no drill down and they hide then.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but how would i pull certain data out without summarizing?

I need to pull ones that correspond with the weeknum and if there isn't one for a certain week, it will either be "missed" or "pending" (I can figure that out).

What i want, is to pull data out from each different detail but when i did it, it is only pulling the latest one rather ones i want to pull. 

So for example, I want to pull out weeknum 30 initial but every time i do it, its giving me the week 39 since that's the last detail report before the group footer.